# how to set alarm manually

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am using Remainder in my App. I have to get the events from the database and the set the details into calendar for setting alarm with Push message.
I have tried some code.

but i could not set the calender manual. Getting Null pointer exception.
My code is here:

```
scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(this);
    scheduleClient.doBindService();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String year = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String months = null;
    if (month.startsWith("0") || month.startsWith("1")) {
        months = year + "-" + month;
    } else {
        months = year + "-" + "0" + month;
    }

    if (isSetToTrue == true) {
        LoadCalender(months);

        // here set your checkBox to true
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check box enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check box disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }


public void LoadCalender(String month) {

    try {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

        cursor = db.getSelectedEventDetails(month);
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("event"));
                    title = "News/Events";
                    String dates = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("date"));

                    try {

                        DateFormat formatter;
                        Date date = new Date();
                        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        date = (Date) formatter.parse(dates);
                        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String todayStr = fmt.format(date);
                        java.sql.Date dt = java.sql.Date
                                .valueOf(new String(todayStr));
                        System.out.println("Today is " + dt);
                        String yr = String.valueOf(dt.getYear());
                        int year = Integer.parseInt("20"+yr.substring(1));
                        int months = dt.getMonth();
                        int day = dt.getDay();

                        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c1.set(year, months+1, day);
                        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date,
                        // this
                        // activity talks to the client that talks to the
                        // service
                        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c1);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // looping through All Contacts

}
```

Logcat error;

```
    03-19 12:23:23.395: W/System.err(2984): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 12:23:23.405: W/System.err(2984):     at com.rathnasoft.reminder.ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(ScheduleClient.java:54)
03-19 12:23:23.426: W/System.err(2984):     at com.rathnasoft.vikasa.HomeActivity.LoadCalender(HomeActivity.java:228)
03-19 12:23:23.446: W/System.err(2984):     at com.rathnasoft.vikasa.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:87)
03-19 12:23:23.466: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-19 12:23:23.475: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-19 12:23:23.506: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-19 12:23:23.518: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-19 12:23:23.525: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-19 12:23:23.556: W/System.err(2984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 12:23:23.577: W/System.err(2984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-19 12:23:23.586: W/System.err(2984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 12:23:23.615: W/System.err(2984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:23:23.635: W/System.err(2984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 12:23:23.645: W/System.err(2984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 12:23:23.666: W/System.err(2984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 12:23:23.676: W/System.err(2984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like `scheduleClient` is `null`. Are you calling `LoadCalender()` from somewhere else? Offtopic: methods in Java by convention start with lower case (e.g. `loadCalendar`, not `LoadCalendar`), and it's spelled "calendAr".

Comment: Plz help me to do this with out using time picker and datepicker

Comment: public ScheduleClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

Comment: Sorry, please see my comment edit.

Comment: Load Calender() method is in mainactivity..can you plz tell me what to do

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix if you don't explain your problem correctly. *Are you calling LoadCalender() from somewhere else?* If yes, post that.

Comment: loadCalendar() changed... but still getting same error

Comment: That's just a style comment, it changes nothing about your problem. Still *Are you calling LoadCalender() from somewhere else? If yes, post that.*

Comment: i use this link with out using datepicker http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/